# How to check whether component has been displayed (*ngIf) in Angular 6 UI Tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to write UI tests for my component in Angular 6 and I want to verify whether my component has been displayed. This component is displaying conditionally by *ngIf.

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of summaryData">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <app-icon *ngIf="data.isFlagSelected"></app-icon>
                {{data.description}}
            </td>
[...]
```

Here what I did:

```
describe("MyComponent", () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement[];
    let elRows: HTMLElement[];

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [MyComponent]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;

            de = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css("table tbody tr"));
            elRows = de.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr.nativeElement), []);
        });
    }));

    it("should display icon when flag === true", () => {

        // data1 has Description SomeRecord_1 and data.isFlagSelected=true
        const data1 = elRows.find(e => e.innerText.includes("SomeRecord_1")).getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        // data2 has Description SomeRecord_2 and data.isFlagSelected=false
        const data2 = elRows.find(e => e.innerText.includes("SomeRecord_2")).getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        expect(data1.getElementsByTagName("app-icon").length).toBeTruthy();
        expect(data2.getElementsByTagName("app-icon").length).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

And it works good! However I wondering whether I did it in right way or I could do it better somehow.

Comment: For me, it looks fine. Whenever element is not shown with ``*ngIf`` it will return ``null` if you try to query it by ``fixture.debugElement.query`` and instance of ``DebugElement`` when element actually appear.

Comment: I don't think this test is useful for you. You're basically testing if Angular works correctly : that's not your job ! instead, you should focus on what your code is doing, in this case you should test if the icon disaplyed is the one you expect. And to do that, you should test the icon component itself, not his parent. His parent should contain a mock at best (but if it's only an icon, the real component should not create any issue).